# Cannot sort keys and values in the array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "PropertiesGroup1": {
            "Size": "Big",
            "Color": "Red"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup2": {
            "City": "Berlin"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup3": {
            "Price": "300$",
            "Rating": "5",
            "In stock": "Yes"
        }
    },

    {
        "PropertiesGroup1": {
            "Size": "Medium",
            "Color": "Blue",
            "Weight" : "35"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup2": {
            "City": "London",
            "Location": "Random"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup3": {
            "Price": "250$",
            "Rating": "3",
            "In Stock": "None"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup4": {
            "Name": "TV",
            "Guarantee": "2 years",
            "Credit": "Yes"
        }
    },

    {
        "PropertiesGroup1": {
            "Size": "Small",
            "Color": "Black",
            "Weight" : "65",
            "Height" : "130"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup2": {
            "City": "Paris",
            "Location": "Rue 105"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup3": {
            "Price": "270$",
            "Rating": "4",
            "In Stock": "None"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup7": {
            "Quantity": "4"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup5": {
            "Type": "Banana",
            "Seller": "James"
        }
    }


]
```

And what I need to get is:

```
[
    {
        "PropertiesGroup1": {
            "Size": "Big | Medium | Small",
            "Color": "Red | Blue | Black",
            "Weight": "35 | 65",
            "Height": "130"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup2": {
            "City": "Berlin | London | Paris",
            "Location": "Random | Rue 105"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup3": {
            "Price": "300$ | 250$",
            "Rating": "5 | 3 | 4",
            "In stock": "Yes | None"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup4": {
            "Name": "TV",
            "Guarantee": "2 years",
            "Credit": "Yes"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup7": {
            "Quantity": "4"
        },
        "PropertiesGroup5": {
            "Type": "Banana",
            "Seller": "James"
        }
    }
]
```

So I need to get all possible groups, their properties, and their values.
I have tried to make it, but i stuck..

Any help will be appreciated a lot!

Here is what I have already tried to do, but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('my.json', 'utf-8'));
let sortedObj = [];
let objectKeys = [];
let finalObject = {};


for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  objectKeys[i] = Object.keys(obj[i]);
}

objectKeysResult = objectKeys[0];

for (j = 1; j < objectKeys.length; j++) {
  objectKeysResult = unite(objectKeysResult, objectKeys[j]);
}
const categories = [];
for (i = 0; i < objectKeysResult.length; i++) {
  key = objectKeysResult[i];
  categories[i] = [...new Set(obj.map(bill => bill[key]))]
  sortedObj[objectKeysResult[i]] = categories[i];
}

let uniqueKeys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...sortedObj[objectKeysResult[0]]));

let keys = Object.keys(sortedObj);

let uniqueValues = [];
let newObject = [];
for (k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
  for (i = 0; i < uniqueKeys.length; i++) {
    uniqueValues[i] = sortedObj[keys[k]].map(function(obj) {
      return obj[uniqueKeys[i]];
    })
    uniqueValues[i] = uniqueValues[i].filter(function(element) {
      return element !== undefined;
    });
    newObject[uniqueKeys[i]] = uniqueValues[i].filter(function(elem, index, self) {
      return index === self.indexOf(elem);
    });
    combinedObject[k] = newObject;
  }
  console.log(newObject);
  finalObject[keys[k]] = combinedObject[k];
}
console.log(finalObject);

function unite() {
  return [].concat.apply([], arguments).filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(elem) === index;
  });
}
```

Comment: please add all relevant parts to the question.

Comment: Hello! What exactly do you mean?

Comment: what you have, what you did and what you want - without visiting another page.

Comment: Oh I couldn't add this to the question due to StackOverflow restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the keys form the object and the keys and values from the inner object and create a new object by collecting the values.

BTW, the keys needs to have the same value for grouping, like `'In Stock'` vs `'In stock'`.

```js
const
    getUnique = (...v) => Array.from(new Set(v)),
    SEPARATOR = ' | ';

var data = [{ PropertiesGroup1: { Size: "Big", Color: "Red" }, PropertiesGroup2: { City: "Berlin" }, PropertiesGroup3: { Price: "300$", Rating: "5", "In Stock": "Yes" } }, { PropertiesGroup1: { Size: "Medium", Color: "Blue", Weight: "35" }, PropertiesGroup2: { City: "London", Location: "Random" }, PropertiesGroup3: { Price: "250$", Rating: "3", "In Stock": "None" }, PropertiesGroup4: { Name: "TV", Guarantee: "2 years", Credit: "Yes" } }, { PropertiesGroup1: { Size: "Small", Color: "Black", Weight: "65", Height: "130" }, PropertiesGroup2: { City: "Paris", Location: "Rue 105" }, PropertiesGroup3: { Price: "270$", Rating: "4", "In Stock": "None" }, PropertiesGroup7: { Quantity: "4" }, PropertiesGroup5: { Type: "Banana", Seller: "James" } }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, p]) => {
            r[k] = r[k] || {};
            Object
                .entries(p)
                .forEach(([l, v]) => r[k][l] = r[k][l]
                    ? getUnique(...r[k][l].split(SEPARATOR), v).join(SEPARATOR)
                    : v);
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```